# Bootstrap carousel: start css animation after slide is complete

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can anyone help me with an example on how to start the animation when the carousel item is active.

I am using daneden.me/animate/‎ his css and the animation starts right after the next item is fired. Now what i want is to let it start after the slide is done.

This is my HTML

```
<div class="item active">               
    <div class="row" style="position:relative;">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <h1 class="animated fadeInLeft">Bespaar kosten met een overstap naar LED!</h1>
               <div class="lead">
               <p class="animated fadeInLeft animation-delay-hs">
                  Met LED verlichting bespaard u al snel <strong>40 tot 60%</strong> op uw energy kosten. <strong>wat LED u?</strong>
               </p>
               <a href="#" class="animated animation-delay-hs fadeInLeft btn btn-default btn-large">Vraag een offerte op maat aan</a>
                 <a href="#" class="animated animation-delay-hs fadeInLeft btn btn-warning btn-large">Lees meer</a>
               </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 hero-led" style="position:absolute; bottom:0; right: 0;">
            <img src="img/hero-1.png" class="animated fadeInRightBig img-responsive hero-led-light" alt="">
            <img src="img/hero-1-light.png" class="animation-delay-2s hero-light-delay animated fadeIn img-responsive" alt="">
            <img src="img/hero-1-light-2.png" class="animation-delay-3s hero-light-delay animated fadeIn img-responsive" alt="">
            <img src="img/hero-1-light-3.png" class="animation-delay-4s hero-light-delay animated fadeIn img-responsive" alt="">
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

The css is loaded from the animated.css from [daneden](http://daneden.me/animate/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When i read you question and see your html code. I do not understand why your transition classes are already in it.

For the transition you will have to start with the element hidden (opacity:0;). After this add the transition class which make it visible with some effect. https://github.com/daneden/animate.css shows how you can do this with jQuery.

I think you should do something like this. Create a carousel and transitions for some slide.
Run the carousal, stop it at your transition slide, play your transition and restart the carousel.

Example with transitions on the second slide (index = 1):

```
$('.carousel').carousel();

$(".carousel").on('slid.bs.carousel', function(evt) {
      if( $(this).find('.active').index() == 1)
      {
            $(this).carousel('pause');

            /* run your transitions */
            transitions();

            /*restart your carousel */
      }   
});
```

Find the index of the active slide: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18690905/1596547
Stop (and restart) your carousel: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14753680/1596547

### Transitions

Bootstrap came with transition.js you could use the th add some fall backs to your code. To prevent your code from running when a transition runs you will need to add it in a timeout. See: [jQuery/Javascript - How to wait for manipulated DOM to update before proceeding with function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342084/jquery-javascript-how-to-wait-for-manipulated-dom-to-update-before-proceeding)

for example a create this function:

```
        function transitions()
        {
        var j = 1;
        for(var i=1; i<=4; i++)
        {
            setTimeout(   
            function()
            {
                    if (!$.support.transition){$('#z'+i).removeClass('inactive')}
                    else
                    {

                    $('#z'+j).addClass('animated').addClass('fadeInLeft');
                    $('#z'+j).one($.support.transition.end, function(){$('#z'+i).removeClass('inactive')}).emulateTransitionEnd(2000);
                    }
                    j++
            },
            2000*(i-1));
        }
        }
```

This code add the transition classes for every z* element. The next transition starts 2 seconds (2000ms in the timeout) after the first.

**html**:

```
           <p class="inactive" id="z1">
              Met LED verlichting bespaart u al snel <strong>40 tot 60%</strong> op uw energie kosten. <strong>wat LED u?</strong>
           </p>
           <p class="inactive" id="z2">
              Met LED verlichting bespaart u al snel <strong>40 tot 60%</strong> op uw energie kosten. <strong>wat LED u?</strong>
           </p>   
           <p class="inactive" id="z3">
              Met LED verlichting bespaart u al snel <strong>40 tot 60%</strong> op uw energie kosten. <strong>wat LED u?</strong>
           </p>   
           <div class="inactive" id="z4">
               <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-large">Vraag een offerte op maat aan</a>
           </div>
```

**css**:

```
        //hide the z* elements
        .inactive{opacity:0;}
```

### Restart

Cause the above code preforms 4 transition of 2 second the carousel will be restart after 5 x 2 seconds:

```
        var that = $(this);
        /*restart your carousal */
        setTimeout(function(){

            that.carousel('next');
            that.carousel('cycle');

            /* hide transitions again */
            $("#slide2 [id^='z']").removeClass().addClass('inactive');


            },2000*5);
```

### Example:

see: http://bootply.com/83200

### Complete code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Carousel with transitions</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
<link href="/bootstrap3/bootstrap-master/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <style>
body {padding-top:80px;}
.inactive{opacity:0;}


 </style>    
    </head>
<body>
<header class="navbar  navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="banner">
<div class="col-10">
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo Text</a>
  </div>

  <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="home_button"> <a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> </a> </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li> <a href="#" > My Account </a> </li><br>
          <li> <a href="#"> Logout </a> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  </div>
</div>
</header>   

<div class="container" style="max-width:900px;">

      <div id="carousel-example-captions" class="carousel slide bs-docs-carousel-example">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-captions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li class="" data-target="#carousel-example-captions" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li class="" data-target="#carousel-example-captions" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <img data-src="holder.js/900x500/auto/#777:#777" src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="900x500">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>First slide label</h3>
              <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item" id="slide2">
            <img data-src="holder.js/900x500/auto/#666:#666" src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="900x500">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Second slide label</h3>
               <p class="inactive" id="z1">
                  Met LED verlichting bespaart u al snel <strong>40 tot 60%</strong> op uw energie kosten. <strong>wat LED u?</strong>
               </p>
               <p class="inactive" id="z2">
                  Met LED verlichting bespaart u al snel <strong>40 tot 60%</strong> op uw energie kosten. <strong>wat LED u?</strong>
               </p>   
               <p class="inactive" id="z3">
                  Met LED verlichting bespaart u al snel <strong>40 tot 60%</strong> op uw energie kosten. <strong>wat LED u?</strong>
               </p>   
               <div class="inactive" id="z4">
                   <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-large">Vraag een offerte op maat aan</a>
               </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img data-src="holder.js/900x500/auto/#555:#5555" src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="900x500">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Third slide label</h3>
              <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-captions" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="icon-prev"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-captions" data-slide="next">
          <span class="icon-next"></span>
        </a>
      </div>

</div>



<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script src="/bootstrap3/bootstrap-master/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script>

function transitions()
{
var j = 1;
for(var i=1; i<=4; i++)
{
    setTimeout(   
    function()
    {
            if (!$.support.transition){$('#z'+i).removeClass('inactive')}
            else
            {

            $('#z'+j).addClass('animated').addClass('fadeInLeft');
            $('#z'+j).one($.support.transition.end, function(){$('#z'+i).removeClass('inactive')}).emulateTransitionEnd(2000);
            }
            j++
    },
    2000*(i-1));
}
}       

$('.carousel').carousel();

$(".carousel").on('slid.bs.carousel', function(evt) {
  if( $(this).find('.active').index() == 1)
  {
            $(this).carousel('pause');

            /* run your transitions */
            transitions();
            var that = $(this);
            /*restart your carousal */
            setTimeout(function(){

                that.carousel('next');
                that.carousel('cycle');

                /* hide transitions again */
                $("#slide2 [id^='z']").removeClass().addClass('inactive');


                },2000*5);
  }   
});


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, This really helped! Bit late reaction but better late then never right :)