# Modifying or configuring Bootstrap 3 carousel to scroll single thumbnails?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Stuck while working with Bootstrap 3 carousel. I have about 15 single images (200x220) and I need to show them 4 images at a time (this, I've been able to do).

The problem... when you click the next button, I only want the images to show one by one, rather then the next group of 4 images. Is there anyway to do this?

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
         <div class="item active">
             <img src="img-1.jpg">
             <img src="img-2.jpg">
             <img src="img-3.jpg">
             <img src="img-4.jpg">
         </div>
         <div class="item">
             <img src="img-1.jpg">
             <img src="img-2.jpg">
             <img src="img-3.jpg">
             <img src="img-4.jpg">
         </div> 
    </div>
    <a class="control-left">Prev</a>
    <a class="control-right">Next</a>
</div>
```

Comment: yes of course, you can preform any javascript action you like on your `<div class="item">`. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060853/bootstrap-carousel-start-css-animation-after-slide-is-complete/19013552 or try to nest carousels, why not. Please make your question more spefic by adding sketches, example and thing you have tried

Comment: I appreciate answer, but I'm not great with JavaScript/jQuery, so not sure... what's going on, but I'll look into more another time. Thank you.

Comment: good luck, see also here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/4359

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see: http://bootply.com/83872

**html**

```
<div class="container" style="width:600px;">        

      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide bs-docs-carousel-example">

        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <img data-src="holder.js/900x200/#777:#777" src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="900x500">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>First slide label</h3>
              <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
              <div class="images"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img data-src="holder.js/900x200/#666:#666" src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="900x500">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Second slide label</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
              <div class="images"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img data-src="holder.js/900x200/#555:#5555" src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="900x500">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Third slide label</h3>
              <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
              <div class="images"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>


</div>
```

**javascript**

```
var images = ['http://placehold.it/100/113300','http://placehold.it/100/44FFFF','http://placehold.it/100/3000FF',
'http://placehold.it/100/FF00FF','http://placehold.it/100/FFFFFF','http://placehold.it/100/000000',
'http://placehold.it/100/4400FF','http://placehold.it/100/4444FF','http://placehold.it/100/4433FF'
];

$('#myCarousel').carousel({interval:4000}); 
$(".item.active div.images").append('<img src="' + images[0] + '" class="img-responsive" style="float:left;">');
setTimeout(function(){
$(".item.active div.images").append('<img src="' + images[1] + '" class="img-responsive" style="float:left;">');
 },1000);
 setTimeout(function(){
$(".item.active div.images").append('<img src="' + images[2] + '" class="img-responsive" style="float:left;">');
 },2000);


$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {  
    $(".item.active div.images").html('');
    }); 
$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
var index=$(this).find('.active').index();
$(".item.active div.images").append('<img src="' + images[((index*3))] + '" class="img-responsive" style="float:left;">');
setTimeout(function(){
$(".item.active div.images").append('<img src="' + images[((index*3)+1)] + '" class="img-responsive" style="float:left;">');
 },1000);
 setTimeout(function(){
$(".item.active div.images").append('<img src="' + images[((index*3)+2)] + '" class="img-responsive" style="float:left;">');
 },2000);});
```

Answer (score -2):

The short answer is no. You actually haven't "shown 4 items at once", you've shown 1, it just happens to have 4 pictures jammed into it.

What you're asking for isn't a novel use case of the Bootstrap carousel, it's a new carousel which just happens to look like it.